# Arranging rows and columns in R

Tags: r

I have an output data frame as below. But I would like to rearrange to achieve the result in df2. Is there a way for me to arrange or group it?

```
 df>
         a_test1  b_test1  c_test1    a_test2  b_test2  c_test2 
Test     Test1    Test1    Test1      Test2    Test2    Test2 
Result   10         9       4          4        3        1



df2>
         a  b  c  
Test1    10 9  4
Test2    4  3  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(a_test1 = 10,
                  b_test1 = 9,
                  c_test1 = 4,
                  a_test2 = 4,
                  b_test2 = 3,
                  c_test2 = 1)
```

You can achieve this with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_sep = "_",
               names_to = c("prefix", "suffix")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = prefix)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  suffix     a     b     c
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 test1     10     9     4
2 test2      4     3     1
```

---

**UPDATE:**

TO asked if it would still work with different column names that contain several underscores as separator:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(a_test1_10 = 10,
                   b_test1_10 = 9,
                   c_test1_10 = 4,
                   a_test2_10 = 4,
                   b_test2_10 = 3,
                   c_test2_10 = 1)

pivot_spec <- data.frame(.name  = colnames(dat2),
                         .value = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                         test_group = c("test1", "test1", "test1", "test2", "test2", "test2"))
```

This pivot_spec looks like:

```
       .name .value test_group
1 a_test1_10      a      test1
2 b_test1_10      b      test1
3 c_test1_10      c      test1
4 a_test2_10      a      test2
5 b_test2_10      b      test2
6 c_test2_10      c      test2
```

and then ou can just continue pivoting. Actually, the whole pivoting now looks much cleaner and you don't need to combine a pivot_longer with a pivot_wider.

```
dat2 %>%
  pivot_longer_spec(pivot_spec)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  test_group     a     b     c
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 test1          10     9     4
2 test2           4     3     1
```

As you can see, createing this `pivot_spec` template makes the whole thing extremely flexible. The `.name` column contains all your required data columns, the `.value` column contains the new column names and maps the old column names to the new ones. And the `test_group` (you can choose whatever name you like) column determines the rows that would be created and which original column should appear in which column.

Comment: Thanks. Is this still possible if I have 2 separators in my column name. For example if my column name is a_test1_10

Comment: It depends. Per default, R would just ignore the second "_" and delete it from the new variables, i.e. it would take a_test1_10 and change it to a_test1. So if the second "_" is irrelevant and you don't need that information, it would still work. If you want to keep "a_test1" together and split up the part that comes after (i.e. "_10") then it won't work aynmore.

Comment: In that case you can ceate a pivot_longer_spec argument where you would create kind of a template hwo the variables should be reshaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the dat, `filter` rows and turn column into rownames.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = everything(), 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'col'), 
                    names_sep = '_') %>%
  dplyr::filter(!grepl('Test', a)) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  tibble::column_to_rownames('col')

#       a b c
#test1 10 9 4
#test2  4 3 1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a_test1 = c("Test1", "10"), b_test1 = c("Test1", 
"9"), c_test1 = c("Test1", "4"), a_test2 = c("Test2", "4"), b_test2 = c("Test2", 
"3"), c_test2 = c("Test2", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Test", 
"Result"))
```